# HTML Post action sends me to php form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

I am a complete novice with PHP, I just want a simple email contact form that will display an error if a required field isn't entered, and will give a thank you message if the email is sent.

When I click my submit button the email does get sent but the website redirects straight to the `/send-email.php` page, which is blank and useless.  The required form fields also don't seem to do anything in the way of preventing an email from being sent if the forms aren't filled.

**HTML form code:**

```
            <form class="contact-form" action="php/send-email.php" method="post" novalidate>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column width-6 pad-1 contact-column">
                        <h5>Your Name*</h5>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-box" tabindex="1" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column width-6 pad-1 contact-column">
                        <h5>Email*</h5>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-box" tabindex="2" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-2">
                    <div class="column width-6 pad-1 contact-column">
                        <h5>Your Website</h5>
                        <input type="text" name="website" class="form-box" tabindex="3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="column width-6 pad-1 contact-column">
                        <h5>Company</h5>
                        <input type="text" name="company" class="form-box" tabindex="4">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column width-12">
                    <input type="text" name="honeypot" class="form-honeypot">
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-2">
                    <div class="column width-12 pad-1">
                        <h5>Your Message*</h5>
                        <textarea name="message" class="form-text" tabindex="5" required></textarea>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message!" class="btn btn-large bg-blue">

                </div>
            </form>
```

Php file

```
<?php 

$recipient = "contact@mysite.com";

$name = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$website = filter_var($_POST["website"], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$company = filter_var($_POST["company"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$subject = "New email from contact form";

$email_content = "Name: $name\n";
$email_content .= "Email: $email\n";
$email_content .= "Website: $website\n";
$email_content .= "Company: $company\n\n";
$email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n\n\n";

if(mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $headers)){
echo "Thanks for the email, we'll get back to as soon as possible!";
}
?>
```

Any help in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought the required field in the html code was supposed to be enough.  The bigger problem I have, though, is that it doesn't stay on my home page, it takes me to the send-email.php page.  Is that supposed to happen?   
Edit: Like, where is the echo supposed to show up?  I thought that the text that's echoed would popup in my browser or something?

Comment: You need `if` clauses as mentioned and if you want to display an error/success message, you should save it to a session on this page, then use a `header()` to redirect to the page you want to end up on, then `echo` the message there from the session.

Comment: So you would have `$_SESSION['email_success'] = "Thanks for the email, we'll get back to as soon as possible!"; header('Location: link/to/final/page.php'); exit;` On the destination page, you would do something like `if(!empty($_SESSION['email_success'])) { echo $_SESSION['email_success']; $_SESSION['email_success'] = NULL; }`

Comment: I understood the need for an if clause, but the session didn't make sense to me.  Thanks so much for the example, I think I can figure it out from here :)

Comment: IF you don't already and want to use the session, you need to have it start on any page you plan to use it. Put `session_start();` first thing on the page that sets and uses `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @user2860957 Well, from what I have deciphered, the form already sends the post to the `php/send-email.php` page via the `action`, so it's not actually redirecting, The only real question is how the page sends the email but doesn't write the success message (they say the page is blank). Considering the OP has no experience in PHP it could be anything that causes the page to be blank (like an error that is not being displayed because there is a lack of `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check for empty input. Try using if else statement. eg.

```
if($name == '')
{
    echo "Please fill in name";
}

else if($var == '')
{
    //error message
}
```

or you can try

```
if($name == '' || $email == '' || $var == '')
{
    echo "Please fill in all the blank";
}
```

I'm quite new too to PHP, so this is just a simple checking. Hope it'll helps!

Comment: Awesome!  I'm completely new so this certainly helps, thanks!